# How to bind a JButton to the Enter Key

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm trying to get the "Send Message" JButton bound to the enter key, but its not working.

The instantiation:

```
sendMessage = new JButton("Send Message");            
sendMessage.addActionListener(new sendMessageButtonListener());
```

The Listener:

```
 class sendMessageButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (messageBox.getText().length() < 1) {

        } else if (messageBox.getText().equals(".clear")) {
            chatBox.setText("Cleared all messages\n");
            messageBox.setText("");
        } else {
            chatBox.append("<" + username + ">:  " + messageBox.getText()
                    + "\n");
            messageBox.setText("");
        }
        messageBox.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: why an ActionListener when you want to check a key ? Use a KeyListener

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Use keystroke with arrow key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171021/java-use-keystroke-with-arrow-key)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to write a KeyListener to listen to the enterkey. The ActionListener cannot listen to keypress-events.

I would recommend you to extract the lines which are in the ActionListener to a method and then call this method in the KeyListener.

It would look something like this:

```
sendMessage .addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {
                    yourFunction();
                }
            }
        });
```

Another solution i found is the following: You can set your button as the defaultbutton on the pane, where it is embedded :

```
pnae.setDefaultButton(sendMessage);
```

This will also get your ActionListener to be triggered, when enter is pressed